Job advertised as PhD position in industry but I don't want to do a PhD only the job. What is the best path forward? Should I try or simply move on?
I just finished my master and I am looking for a job. There are many jobs that fit my profile and sound very interesting but are advertised as PhD positions in industry. I don't want to do a PhD yet (due to private reasons perhaps I'll have to move to another city after 1.5 years).
What is the best path forward?
I see 4 possible options:

Not applying to these jobs.
Ask before applying if there is a possibility of not doing a PhD.
Ask after discussing my application if I am invited to an interview.
The unethical option, do not mention my intentions of not fully completing the PhD.

I don't feel comfortable with option 4, and that if that's the case I'll prefer option 1.
I will be very happy if you could give your opinion on what is the best possible path forward that would be beneficial for me and a responsible choice with the company that I apply for.
I am located in Germany if that's useful.
Thank you very much!

Can you clarify? Are these positions that require a Ph.D. or actual; Ph.D. programs where you are supposed to work on your Ph.D. The latter one isn't all that common and typically comes with less compensation.

It is the second option. I will work in a company, the research done during that time will end up being my Ph.D work. The positions do not require a Ph.D

Do you think you can hide the fact that you aren't in a PhD program at your job?

This may be more appropriate for the academia SE. The description here is very clear of you are familiar with academia, but as the comments and previous answer show probably not outside of it. Admittedly, the situation is somewhere at the border.

Can you please clarify on how far the jobs "fit my profile and sound very interesting" when you are not actually interested in the PhD part? PhD positions, both in and outside of academic institutions, are usually geared for the specifics of a PhD in terms of tasks, workload, timescale, and so on. The PhD stuff is likely going to be 50% and upwards of the job, so not being interested in that would make the jobs rather unattractive.

I'd definitely apply and/or seek to have a conversation with the people hiring for these positions. You can ask about the PhD placement, their reasons for doing so and more details. In different companies there might be different reasons and levels of flexibility so to the more people you talk the better.
The secondary benefit is you get a foot in the door anyway, make connections, maybe ask them for an advice on your career given your situation. Ask if they can offer you an 18 month contract instead, and if you end up not moving, you can stay.
My biggest lesson after I graduated was that these 'rules' of the job market are imaginary, there are always options and people are willing to be flexible if they are interested.
Hope it helps, best of luck!

usa
Note: this applies to people in the US, I don't know how the "I'll pay you to get a degree" works in places where high education is subsidized.
"due to private reasons perhaps I'll have to move to another city after 1.5 years)."
All of the jobs I know that include a "We will help you get your degree (masters, PhD) as you do this job", tend to contractually require you to complete said degree, and require that you work for them for several years after you get your PhD (4-5 is what I have seen).
They are not looking for someone who is going to work for them for 1.5 years and then leave. If they know that is your plan. They will hire someone else.
And before you think, "then I just won't tell them that" (Which I support for most cases, especially warm body jobs). In this case, that is a bad idea. This long term employment is usually enforced in the employment contract and will have a set of not insignificant penalties (equal to the cost of the degree you were required to get) for failing to get the degree and/or leaving before your time is up. Which is usually pro-rated based on the number of years your worked for them after graduating with a PhD.
PhDs cost about 32K a year here in the US.
Positions that do this exist because the business needs someone with a very specific set of skills/qualifications the degree and cannot find someone who meets those qualifications. So they spend time/money to give someone the degree/skills they need for the job.
And they expect that individual to pay them back for the investment. Hence a long term employment contract with penalties for early departure.
